# how do i display name from server to angular.js?

Tags: node.js, ionic4, angular8, node-oracledb

hello I want to display the user name after he/she log in. in postman i get **"Bienvenu a toi lucie"** from the server but when i run it with angular.js through the browser it gives me the **"Bienvenu a toi undefined"** from the server.
Here is my code: 
protected_things(auth-service):

```
getprotected(name) {
return this.http.get(`${this.url}/api/protected_things?i=${name}&plot=full&apikey=${this.apiKey}`).pipe(
  catchError(e => {
    let status = e.status;
    if (status === 401) {
      this.showAlert('You are not authorized for this!');
      this.logout();
    }
    throw new Error(e);
  })
)
```

}
   **tab1.ts**

```
let name = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('name');

// Get the information from the API
this.authService.getprotected(name).subscribe(res => {
  this.data = res;
});
```

**API**

function get(req, res, next) {

```
oracledb.getConnection(
    config.database,
    function(err, connection){
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }

        connection.execute(
            'select name as "name" '+
            'from grace_users ' +
            'where name = :name ',
            { name: req.body.name},// binds
            {
                outFormat: oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT
            },
            function(err, results, name){

                var usere;
                if (err) {
                    connection.release(function(err) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.error(err.message);
                        }
                    });


                    return next(err);
                }


                name = req.body.name;
                usere = results.rows[0];
               res.status(200).json(`Bienvenu a toi ${name}`);
                //res.send(`Bienvenu a toi ${name}`);


                 connection.release(function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err.message);
                    }
                });
            }
        );
    }
);
```

}

module.exports.get = get;

Comment: The error in your question title doesn't appear to come from the code you posted.

Comment: im sorry instead of usere i used name. in postman i get "Bienvenu a toi lucie" but when i run angular i get Bienvenu a toi undefined.

Comment: usere = results.rows[0];
                    name = req.body.name
                    res.status(200).json(`Bienvenu a toi ${name}`);

Comment: @gracelle please edit the title and question to show where the error exists and how it is triggered

Comment: @TomasVancoillie it is done

Comment: Not related to the question but, in Node.js, you'll find it easier to use the async/await style of programming instead of callbacks, see node-oracledb examples like https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/v4.1.0/examples/webappawait.js#L114-L139  For a web app, you should use a connection pool, which is also shown in the same example.  The blog post https://jsao.io/2018/03/creating-a-rest-api-with-node-js-and-oracle-database/ is useful too.

Answer (score 0):

Your API is expecting your front-end to be sending a `POST` request with an object in the body such as:

```
{
    "name": "paul"
}
```

But your angular service is sending a `GET` request.

Either change the client side to be something like:

```
return this.http.post(`${this.url}/api/protected_things?plot=full&apikey=${this.apiKey}`, { name: name }).pipe(
```

OR

Change the server side to expect the name as part of a `GET` request, which would mean changing any mention of `req.body.name` to `req.query.name`, it might be worth pointing out that your original `GET` requestz was sending the name as a querystring parameter named `i`, which may or may not have been what you wanted

edit:

as you have stated that you would prefer a `GET` request, then I suggest changing your service call line to the following:

```
return this.http.get(`${this.url}/api/protected_things?name=${name}&plot=full&apikey=${this.apiKey}`).pipe(
```

(change `i=${name}` to `name=${name}`)

Comment: okay thank you let me try it out. but my aims is a get request

Comment: I did still the same